# How to fix string formatting in Python?

Tags: python, string, formatting

I just wrote a code, everything is okay, but the code doesn't work I restarted my machine and still doesn't work don't know why?
here is an snippet

```
import datetime
my_date = datetime.datetime(2016,4,25,1,2,5)
print("{%B %d, %Y}".format(my_date))
```

this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\Basir Payenda\PycharmProjects\python_work\demo3.py", line 3, in <module>
    print("{%B %d, %Y}".format(my_date)) 
KeyError: '%B %d, %Y'
```

please help me solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put a colon after brackets, which defines a format.

```
import datetime
my_date = datetime.datetime(2016,4,25,1,2,5)
print("{:%B %d, %Y}".format(my_date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
import datetime
my_date = datetime.datetime(2016,4,25,1,2,5)
# Different ways of formatting
print("{:%B %d, %Y}".format(my_date))  # Using .format  
print(my_date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")) # Using strftime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format.

```
import datetime
my_date = datetime.datetime(2016,4,25,1,2,5)
print(my_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))
# Output: 04/25/2016, 01:02:05
print(my_date.strftime("%B, %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S"))
#Output: April, 25, 2016, 01:02:05
```

Date object has default method to convert string. So you should use that .

More information: [Date format](http://strftime.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> print(my_date.strftime("{%B %d, %Y}"))
{April 25, 2016}
```